# React-Router 4 catch all route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

My React routes are defined as follows:

```
...
<Route component={Header} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
<Route component={Footer} />
...
```

I want to define a catch all route that catches anything that does not match the Landing, About or Contact routes, and instead redirects to a 404 Not found page. How can I do it with React Router 4?

Comment: use <Switch> component https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this implementation

```
const AppRouter = (props) => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Two things: a) I thought this would render `NotFoundPage in all pages; and, 
 b) You don't need `<Header />`twice, as it is in the code, I think.

Comment: Within `Switch` only 1 match will ever be rendered. A `Route` without a `path` is always a match. Therefore, if nothing else matches, `NotFoundPage` will be rendered. Neither the `Header` nor `Footer` should be included within the `Switch` (i've submitted an edit to this answer to fix that part of the code)

Comment: A small note, Routes must be _direct_ children of `<Switch>`, which is to say you cannot have your Routes in a fragment for example.

Comment: Switch not supported in v6

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this will work for you as I have some 3rd party babel wrappers in use, but I get away with declaring all my routes then last putting

```
<Route path="/*" render={() => <SomeComponent /* possible prop injection */ />}/>
```

I've used this fairly frequently, but you can also use

```
<Route render={() => <SomeComponent />} />
```

I don't use this much as I prefer more landmarks in my code, but I got the above from 
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-handling-404-pages/

Comment: bonus: `<SomeComponent />` can be `<Redirect />`

Comment: Indeed it can! I only used `SomeComponent` because in most of my code, my 404 page is a custom component, and would rather render than than a wrapped redirect. But for simple/static 404 pages, `Redirect` does its job well

Answer (score 2):

React has a component called switch from 'react-router-dom'

So By wrapping your Routes inside of Switch, React Router will only render the first Route that matches. Meaning all other routes that don't match will be caught by specifying a route that doesn't have a attribute. See https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-handling-404-pages/

Comment: For anyone wondering why this may not work, if you've declared your routes separately from the switch, this may be why. For example if you have a `const routes = <>... routes </>` and try to do a `return (<Switch>{routes}</Switch>)` it will not work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner to redirect all other routes (placed after all other routes):

```
<Route path="/*" loader={() => redirect('/')} />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
<Route path="/*" render={() => ( < SomeComponent /> /* possible prop injection */ )}  />
```

Here I'm catching all non-existent routes and pushing them to a 404 component:

```js
<Route path="/*" render={() => (  <PagesError404 /> )} />
```

**Remember**

- `path`  = `'/youreRoute'` but also = `{['/']}` attributed
- `exact` = exact match