# react routing issues when routes other that in routing config are hit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a web app with different routes.

There is this case where if a user hits any arbitrary route then he gets directed to Login Component. But it only handles case where bad routing happens this way `localhost:3000/gvgdvgdvgd`.

I have routes such as `/home/news`. A user may end up hitting `/home/news/10` manually which doesn't exist. Similarly there is a route such as coupon and user may end up hitting `/coupons/88` without going to coupons first.

How do I handle these issues in my web-app? I handled it for the first case. Here is the routing config.

```
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginLoadable} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/maths" component={Maths} />
    <Route
     exact
     path="/"
    render={routeProps => (
       <Component1
        {...routeProps}
      />
     )}
   />
   <Route component={LoginLoadable}/>
```

What about the case where user hits `maths/123/1ydhd` manually when that doesn't exist?

Comment: check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457480/react-router-4-catch-all-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457480/react-router-4-catch-all-route)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your routes in a `Switch` and add a `Route` with no `path` prop that renders your 404 page. If you don't specify a path, it should always render that route. Adding a `Switch` makes sure only one route will render. Also you will need to add the `exact` prop to your routes. See:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool for how it matches sub-routes.

Something like:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginLoadable} />
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/maths" component={Maths} />
    <Route
     exact
     path="/"
    render={routeProps => (
       <Component1
        {...routeProps}
      />
     )}
   />
   <Route component={LoginLoadable}/> // <-- remove this since you render it in '/login'
   <Route component={A404Page} // <-- add this
</Switch>
```